# Normal distribution question exercise doesnt give enough information?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

The question:

The time required for the construction of a building has a mean of 6210 days and a  standard deviation of 400 days.Find the time needed for the construction of the building with a probability <0.9

It is given that P(0<=z<=1.28) = 0.4

Since the mean is not 0 and standard deviation is not 1 we have to convert the distribution of time of construction of the building to a normal distribution->

$$P(\frac{0-6210}{400}<=\frac{x-6210}{400}<=\frac{1.28-6210}{400})$$

and doing some math we end up with:

$$P(-15.525<=z<=-15.52) $$

however I dont understand how to continue this exercise.Help appreciated!

Comment: You would have enough information if you read *Find the time needed for the construction of the building with a probability $<0.9$* as *Find the time needed for the construction of the building so it is complete by that time with a probability of $0.9$*

Comment: $1.28$ standard deviations above the mean is $1.28 \times 400 +6210$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not asked for a symmetric interval probability. I give you some explanation to manage the exercise.  It is asked for the probability where $X$ is lower than $x^u$. So the equation is

$$P\left(\frac{X-6210}{400}\leq \frac{x^u-6210}{400}\right)=0.9$$

The standardized random variable $Z=\frac{X-6210}{400}$ is right. With it, the  probability becomes $P\left( Z\leq \frac{x^u-6210}{400}\right)=0.9$. Next we can split the interval and we obtain

$$P\left(Z\leq 0\right)+P\left(0\leq  Z\leq \frac{ x^u-6210}{400}\right)=0.9$$

$Z$ is symmetric distributed around the mean $z=0$. Therefore the equation can be written as

$$0.5+P\left(0\leq  Z\leq \frac{ x^u-6210}{400}\right)=0.9$$

$$P\left(0\leq  Z\leq \frac{ x^u-6210}{400}\right)=0.4$$

With the given hint we get the equation $ \frac{x^u-6210}{400}=1.28$. Finally the required construction time  can be easily calculated.